# Variable contained in Lambda expression not defined

Tags: c#, lambda

Please see the code excerpt below, which I found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
static void SimpleContinuation()
      {
         string path = @"C:\users\public\TPLTestFolder\";
         try
         {
            var firstTask = new Task(() => CopyDataIntoTempFolder(path));
            var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((t) => CreateSummaryFile(path));
            firstTask.Start();
         }
         catch (AggregateException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
         }
      }
```

I am confused by the Lambda expression:

```
var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((t) => CreateSummaryFile(path));
```

What is the purpose of: `(t)`? and why is it contained in brackets? t is not defined anywhere.

I have read this webpage, however it has not answered my question: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx`

Comment: It's passing the task to the continuation, which requires it (it's [defined as an `Action<Task>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx)) but doesn't use it.

Comment: The lambda requires that the signature includes a parameter. That doesn't mean it has to use it in the body.

Comment: "Why is it contained in brackets?" It doesn't have to be. Maybe it's done to look consistent or as a coding convention. "`t` is not defined anywhere" It is defined right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx)  needs an `Action<Task>` - a "method" that accepts a `Task` as its argument. `t` will be the `Task` argument that `ContinueWith` will supply that method with.

That method being something like:

```
void noName(Task t)
{
    CreateSummaryFile(path);
}
```

`ContinueWith` will then execute this anonymous method at the appropriate time supplying it with `t` (which will be ignored), and calling `CreateSummaryFile(path)`.

Answer (score 1):

It would perhaps be a bit clearer if you realise that the form used there is a shorthand and the full form is:

```
(Task t) => CreateSummaryFile(path)
```

It defines an `Action<Task>` and so the counter to `t is not defined anywhere` is that it is in fact defined there.

You're allowed to leave out the type when it can be inferred from context (as it is here). You're also allowed to leave out the parentheses when there is exactly one parameter, so this could also be:

```
t => CreateSummaryFile(path)
```

Now, `t` isn't used here, but it often is and that can be very useful. More so when `ContinueWith` is called on a `Task<TResult>` as then the type of `t` would be `Task<TResult>` and the result could be used in the subsequent task.

Some people like to use `_` for parameters that aren't used to signal "I have to put a parameter here, but it's not doing anything. But then some people hate that convention too. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks.  If there is a function like this: Foo(int t), then the caller has to provide the value of 't'.  In the case of continues with: t is not defined.

Comment: Ah. We would normally say that `Foo` *defines* `t`, not the caller. The caller of course passes a value, and similarly here the implementation of `ContinueWith` passes in the value, which will be the `Task` that has just completed. You can see this by e.g. experimenting with writing properties of the task to the console.

Answer (score 0):

[The signature of `ContinueWith` is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd270696(v=vs.140).aspx):

```
Task ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)
```

The `Action<Task>` part means that you have to pass a delegate with one input parameter of type `Task` and a return of `void`. That is, `ContinueWith` will call that delegate at an appropriate time and pass an argument of type `Task`.

A lamdba expression in C# is a shorthand for a delegate. To the left of the lambda operator ( `=>` ) are the parameters, to the right the body that will be executed. Since you will get an argument of type `Task`, you will need a parameter of that type. In your case that is `t`. That you don't need this value makes no difference. You still need to declare it to satisfy the lamdba expression's signature.